# Интерполяция увеличенных изображений в разных браузерах

Tags: изображения, браузер, кроссбраузерность, интерполяция

Почему очень сильно увеличенная картинка выглядит пикселизированой в FireFox под OS X (и, вроде бы, под Android) в отличие от того же FireFox под Windows и прочих браузеров?

Есть ли способ повлиять на применяемую интерполяцию, чтобы микроизображение, растянутое в сотни раз, выглядило приятно размытым во всех браузерах? Из приведённых скриншотов, «правильно» выглядит только у Chrome.

Использовалась тестовая картинка 9x5px. Белый фон и 5 чёрных пикселей (увеличенное изображение):

[image: Тестовая картинка 9x5px]

Картинка растягивалась браузером до 900x500 через `background-size: cover`. Вот, как это выглядит в разных браузерах:

Chrome 47, Mac OS X (отлично, все бы так): [image: Chrome / OS X]

Firefox 43.0.4, Mac OS X: [image: FF / OS X]

Firefox 43.0.4, Windows 8: [image: FF / OS X]

Comment: предлагаю делать подобные картинки в виде svg. Тогда они будут скорее всего одинаковые и минимум размытые.

Comment: @KoVadim [идея](http://gradient.quasi.ink/) была добиться несколькими пикселями изображения ровных, приятно размытых фонов, кроссбраузерно. Но, FF/OSX всю малину портит.

Comment: нужна кроссбраузерная размытость - либо пусть дизайнер рисует, либо css.

Завтра алгоритм растеризации поменяют и все.

Comment: @KoVadim «дизайнер рисует» тяжёлые, по сравнению с 9x5px, изображения. CSS умеет только линейный либо радиальный градиент. Наложение градиентов существенно ограничено – цвета блекнут при множестве наложений.